# Mock pyodbc objects for Python testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyodbc

> Disclaimer* I'm not asking how to inject my mock into my unit test
>   with `unittest.mock`.  This is about to how to model a mock of
>   `pyodbc`.

I need to get a mock of some `pyodbc` objects going so I can test various functions of my Python app, but i'm finding it exceptionally hard to do.  Traditionally the way to do this is just to inherit from the object I want to mock and then override any troublesome methods or properties with static values to test against.

However, when I try to inherit from `pyodbc.Connection` or `pyodbc.Row` i get the error:

> TypeError: type 'pyodbc.Connection' is not an acceptable base type

I can grab the class objects themselves and pass them around, but that's not a good idea for a number of reasons, nor will the functionality of my tests be very representative of the deployment context.

Anyone have an idea on how to do this in Python?